# Would/will when the statement stands true

Tags: tense-agreement

I was wondering how things **would** go this coming Monday?

I was wondering how things **will** go this coming Monday?

Let's say you were wondering that two days ago, and Monday is yet to come.
What tense would you use here?
Are both fine?
Would using either be fine?

Comment: In  English, we always capitalize the days of the week. Also we say "_this_ coming Monday" to denote the next Monday on the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

If the wondering took place clearly in the past, two days ago, as you say:

> I was wondering how things would go this coming Monday.

If you were still wondering up until a few moments ago and are explaining to someone what has been on your mind:

> I was wondering how things will go this coming Monday.

**will** (re)sets the focus to present looking towards the future.

**would** (re)sets the focus to past looking towards what was then the future.

It just so happens that **this coming Monday** is future for the present and thus must have been in the future for the past moment too. You can remove it from the sentence as it's a red herring.

> I was wondering how things would go.
>
> I was wondering how things will go.
>
> I was wondering how things would go at the recital yesterday.
>
> I was wondering how things  will go at the recital tomorrow.

Comment: Let's say Monday here, plays a significant role.
And that the other person wouldn't be able to understand what I'm talking about if I left that part out. 
In this case, both would, and will work, right?